# UITextView doesn't show letters corrextly

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, utf-8, uitextview

I am trying to figure out with UITextView. I use this line to show newsStory.text in my UITextView.
`NSLog(@"%@",  newsStory.text);`

`[newsStory setValue:newsStory.text forKey:@"contentToHTMLString" ];`

In NSLog encoding is Ok

[image]

But when i am running the app, i see not-understandable symbols:
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you use supported public API?

Comment: Em, forKey:@"contentToHTMLString" is not public API? 0o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware of two ways of doing this properly:

- UIWebView -loadHTMLString:baseURL:
- parse html into an `NSAttributedString` with https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText and then use `NSAttributedString` with `UITextView`

Comment: Thanks! This one:
UIWebView -loadHTMLString:baseURL:
helped)